# How to add labels to legend using leaflet in r

Tags: r

I'm putting together a choropleth in r but having trouble with the legend that appears in the bottom right corner. It gives me the specified values that I want but fails to pick up the labels. Without the labels the numbers seem a bit too random to interpret. Code I've used is...

```
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addScaleBar(position="bottomleft") %>% 
  addPolygons(data=basemap.LA, 
              stroke=TRUE, 
              color="black",
              weight=2,
              fillOpacity = 0.5, 
            fillColor=~data.choropleth.LA.palette(basemap.LA$choroplethdata),
              label=~basemap.LA$LA15NM, # labels
              popup=paste("Score: ",basemap.LA$choroplethdata),
              group="choropleth data") %>% 

  addLegend("bottomright", pal=data.choropleth.LA.palette, values = basemap.LA$choroplethdata, labels = basemap.LA$urban_rural_name,  title="Rurality")
```

Trying to get the legend to produce something along lines of

2 Really rural
3 Fairly rural
4 Fairly urban
5 Really urban

All of these names appear in the specified column but it doesn't add anything to the legend